# Do the market place / fishing guy / photo guy / dog tag quests in FFXV ever end?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Do the market place / fishing guy / photo guy / dog tag quests in FFXV ever end?

As in, if I keep going back, will they just continue to generate and give me quests? I like being a completionist, and sometimes this kind of thing can trip me up and leave me spending hours chasing a end I can never reach.

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/293019/162442)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the quests you mentioned do have a definitive end. I will summarize the ones you alluded to below, but a comprehensive list of all side quests can be found [here](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Quest_(Final_Fantasy_XV)/Sidequests).

Food Retrieval (retrieved from [Takka](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Takka_(Final_Fantasy_XV)) in [Hammerhead](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Hammerhead_(Final_Fantasy_XV))): The market quests end with the [A Meat Most Magnificent](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-15/A_Meat_Most_Magnificent) quest.

Fishing (retrieved from Navyth the fisherman in [Duscae](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Duscae)): The fishing side quests end with the [Angler's Nightmare](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-15/Angler%27s_Nightmare) quest.

Photos (retrieved from [Vyv](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Vyv) in [Lestallum](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Lestallum)): the photo quests end with the [Cursed Canvas](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-15/The_Cursed_Canvas) Quest, and a full list of these photo quests can be found [here](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-04-01-final-fantasy-15-vyv-quests-every-photo-location-4386).

Dog Tags (originally retrieved from [Dave](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Dave_Auburnbrie) in [Longwythe Rest Area](http://finalfantasyxv.wiki.fextralife.com/Longwythe+Rest+Area), though his location changes as you progress through his side quest): the dog tag quests end with [Witch of the Woods](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-15/The_Witch_of_the_Woods). A full list of the dog tag quests, as well as Dave's location to initiate each quest, can be found [here](https://thefantasygamer.com/2016/12/01/gone-hunting-final-fantasy-xv-side-quest/).

Market Discounts (retrieved from various merchants in Lestallum, though mostly in [Duscae](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Duscae) and [Cleigne](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cleigne)): these quests provide market discounts. A list of these quests and their rewards can be found [here](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Quest_(Final_Fantasy_XV)/Sidequests#Lestallum_Merchants).

As far as I know (and as mentioned in Vemonus' answer), the only endless quests are the hunting quests.

Comment: Wanna be extra awesome, when does the guy requesting food in the resturant end too? ;)

Comment: Let me check, if I find it I'll revise my answer :D

Comment: Which food quest are you talking about more specifically? The quests where you have to fetch food are the ones I called market above, though they are retrieved from Takka at the Crow's Nest Diner. I'm happy to edit the answer to be more clear if this is what you're referring to.

Comment: The one quest I remember the name of right now is 'Everyone Loves Beans'

Comment: Yes, those are the ones I marked as Market above. I'll change that now.

Comment: Ok, the 'other' food quests are the market stalls where you get reduced prices - I'm presuming they also have an end? Would you mind providing that too? Making better answers is awesome :)

Comment: Again, do you have a more specific example of the quest? Happy to add it if I can find something on it. I know there are missions to reduce prices, but I think they're of a different kind than these ones, if only because they're scattered throughout the game, and do not progress as deeply or reward the player in the same ways as the quests above (as far as I know)

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein I believe he's talking about in the city that Vyv is outside of. I forget the name, since it's been 5 months or so since I played FFXV, but the stalls in the marketplace have quests that I think end up lowering prices for you. That or they make more items available...

Comment: @Vemonus Updated (and look, I spelled your name right this time!!)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all of those quests have a set number of side quests and all have an overarching storyline that have a definitive ending.

The only quests that are endless/repeatable are the Hunting Quests.